# Open port on Google Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall, rethinkdb, compose-db, google-cloud-shell

Update: The problem described in this question is no longer relevant as the limitation that caused this problem has been lifted. Feel free to create a new question may you encounter similiar issues but as far as I know, the problem I faced was caused by a limitation that has been lifted.

In the Google Cloud Shell I try to connect through the proxy connection string with RethinkDB I am running on Compose to test my application before deploying however it seems that the port (or something else?) has been blocked. I tried to tellnet as a compose support engineer suggested however he had not much expierence with GCS either.

So I tried this:

```
telnet <url-of-rethinkdb> 15407
```

However it states the following:

```
Trying <ip-of-rethinkdb>...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

So my question is, supposing it is the firewall causing this, where can I update the firewall rules for the Google Cloud Shell? (If possible at all)

Also if their might be a different reason for this to happen, suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limitations mentioned above are no longer imposed. The documentation does not mention them and I tested personally by connecting to a random TCP port with success.

Answer (score 7):

Update: As @FedKad mentioned, the port limitations are no longer imposed.

As stated on the Google Cloud Platform documentation, the outgoing connections of the Google Cloud Shell are limited to the following ports:

20, 21, 22, 80, 443, 2375, 2376, 3306, 8080, 9600, and 50051.

This is located in the limitations section so assume there is no way to do this.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations

Comment: Thanks for that reference. I could find all these ports in the IANA list, except https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=50051

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers you're welcome, was a pain in the ass for me to find out as well ;-)